# xcopy - copy at least one file matching a pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

Whenever `xcopy` fails to find a file, it changes the `errorLevel` variable from `0` to something else.
In our company we have large scripts that copy files using `xcopy` and take actions based on this `errorLevel`.

It works absolutely fine for specific files or directories.

**Works absolutely fine:**

```
xcopy file dir
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit -1
```

However, if, instead of specifying the exact name of a file I want to use a `*`, then checking `errorLevel` would no longer work.

**Doesn't work:**

```
xcopy file* dir
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit -1
```

I'll get:

> File not found - file*
>
> 0 File(s) copied

But `errorLevel` would be `0`.

How can I make sure that at least 1 file is copied when using the wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xcopy` command, when using wildcards, does not consider zero matching files as an error.

As a work-around, you can use the `where` command to check if there is at least one matching item, in which case it sets the `ErrorLevel` to `0`, but to `1` otherwise. Adding the switch `/Q` prevents `where` from outputting anything and lets it just return the `ErrorLevel`:

```
where /Q "file*"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit -1
xcopy "file*" "dir"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit -1
```

You cannot do a single check of `ErrorLevel`, because `xcopy` will overwrite the `ErrorLevel` of `where`. However, you can shorten the above like this:

```
where /Q "file*" || exit -1
xcopy "file*" "dir" || exit -1
```

Or even like this:

```
where /Q "file*" && xcopy "file*" "dir" || exit -1
```

---

I have put all file and directory specifications in between quotation marks here, because this is the only secure way in case any of them contain white-spaces.